# Return 2 variables from the servlet after ajax query

Tags: java, ajax, jsp, servlets

I post to my servlet via AJAX this:

```
$.ajax({    
    url: 'myServlet?action=Doeth',
    type: 'post',
    data: {machine: i, name: txt, status:status}, // i have initilized the values before
    success: function (data) {
        $('#fep').val(data);            
    }    
});
```

back in my servlet I have:

```
if(jspAction.equals("Doeth")){

    int status = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("status"));     
    int name = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("name")); 
    String machine = request.getParameter("machine");

    //do some stuff and assign in 2 variables
    //fep = "a value" and var2="some more"

    response.getWriter().write(String.valueOf(fep));

}
```

So in success the following input is filled with the value `fep`

```
<input id="fep" class="form-control" name="fep" required>
```

If I want to return not only one value but 2 from the servlet (lets say the variable `var2`, how I do this? I tried

```
response.getWriter().write(String.valueOf(fep));
response.getWriter().write(String.valueOf(var2));
```

but it didn't work

Comment: have you tried to return a composite object? or fep.toString() + "SEPARATOR" + var2.toString() ?

Comment: Why wouldn't you just return JSON?

Comment: either use a library (like Jackson) to return some JSON or build the json string yourself with something like `response.getWriter().write(String.format("{\"fep\":\"%s\", \"var2\":\"%s\"}",fep, var2));`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A `Servlet` can't return multiple results. It's function is to handle an HTTP request and produce a single corresponding HTTP response.

If you need to pass data in the response, you need to choose an appropriate format and serialise it. The most common thing you can use, is JSON.

JSON is a text - based data format, that can represent complex objects and data structures. There is also a wide variety of libraries for working with it.